# Unable to push to remote GIT repository -- "[...] does not appear to be a git repository"

Tags: git, version-control, client, remote-server

I've set up my GIT repository on my server using the following in the appropriate folder (the root of my subdomain, `git.mydomain.com`):

```
mkdir foo.git
cd foo.git
git init --bare --shared
```

This would make the repository available by the URL `git.mydomain.com/foo.git`.

On my client, trying to push the commited files to the server using the following:
mkdir foo

```
cd foo
git init
git remote add foo myUser@git.mydomain.com:foo.git
git add readme.txt
git commit -m "foo"
git push foo master
.. entering user password ..
```

Only results in:

```
fatal: 'foo.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

However, following a set of different guides, I seem to be unable to resolve this problem. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated, please bear in mind that I'm quite green to GIT.

Comment: What happens if you use the following push command: git push myUser@git.mydomain.com:foo.git master

Comment: @PeterRitchie That sadly gives me the same error.

Comment: Seems very similar to this: http://thelucid.com/2008/12/02/git-setting-up-a-remote-repository-and-doing-an-initial-push/  But that includes invoking git_update_server_info

Comment: @PeterRitchie Indeed, that's (one of..) the guide I've followed, however, using `git update-server-info` changes nothing ;-/.

Comment: Trying to visit my repo on a browser yields a 403 error? Could that be a contributing factor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line `git remote add foo myUser@git.mydomain.com:foo.git` assumes that the directory foo.git is in the home directory of the `myUser` user. You're much better off using an absolute path e.g. `git remote add foo myUser@git.mydomain.com:/home/gitrepos/foo.git`

If you're on a shared server, you can check your home path by executing:

```
echo $HOME
```

Which, in my case, yields:

> home/u/01234/

If I've stored my repositories in the www/git/ folder in my home-path, the command might look something like this:

```
git remote add origin myUser@mydomain.com:/home/u/01234/www/git/foo.git
```

Comment: Thanks a million for this answer, it solved my question. I'll edit your answer, if you don't mind, and add some basic information about how I found the specific path, to make it even more noob-friendly.

Comment: Thanks @Zar. I'm glad that I was able to help you solve it. I really appreciate you expanding on my answer (as I went offline and couldn't follow up) to help anyone else with a similar situation.