# Unable to push to remote repository in Git

Tags: git, push, msysgit

I am trying to implement a simple scenario where I have a git repo on one server and I am able to push this repo to a remote server. After resolving many other issues, I am stuck at the following stage:

On server1, I have a git repo. Now I follow the steps outlined at http://thelucid.com/2008/12/02/git-setting-up-a-remote-repository-and-doing-an-initial-push/

i.e. 
1) ssh to remote server
2) create a directory
3) Bare init a repo
4) exit and on local server add remote using the following statement

```
   git remote add api User@example.com:/Myproj.git
```

5) Push to remote. (git push -u api master)

The error I get is

```
git: '/Myproj.git' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

How to fix this? I am using MsysGit 1.7.10 and the ssh server is Cygwin on both the servers.

=======================

Adding output of GIT_TRACE=2 git push -u api master

```
$ GIT_TRACE=2 git push -u api master
trace: built-in: git 'push' '-u' 'api' 'master'
trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'Administrator@api.example.com' 'git-receive-pack '\''
/Myproj.git'\'''
git: '/Myproj.git' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

======================

Output of GIT_TRACE=2 git push -u api master (after doing global git config change)

$ GIT_TRACE=2 git push -u api master
trace: built-in: git 'push' '-u' 'api' 'master'
trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'Administrator@api.example.com' 'git receive-pack '\''
/MyProj.git'\'''
fatal: '/MyProj.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you need is to remove a slash and run:

```
git remote add api User@example.com:Myproj.git
```

Comment: I have also tried giving the full path as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571173/unable-to-push-to-remote-git-repository-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-re but I get the same error, just with a different path.

Comment: Add output of `GIT_TRACE=2 git push -u api master` to the question. It will show more information.

Comment: You may need to run `git config --local remote.api.receivepack "git receive-pack"` for local repository as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2745562/1535516)

Comment: And how did the output of `GIT_TRACE=2 ...` change?

Comment: Sorry, the error now was different, didn't notice that earlier. It now says /MyProj.git does not appear to be a git repository.

Comment: Either the path is incorrect (maybe try to use full path) or the directory is really not a repository (if you accidentally inited wrong directory).

Comment: I removed the colon from the path and it worked then. Thanks for also showing how to debug. Learn a thing or two today.